# Connection Reset Error on Solana Transactions

Tags: solana-program, web3.js, solana-cli, rpc, solana-test-validator

I'm currently facing a challenge with my Solana project, and I'm reaching out to seek your expertise.

In my setup, I'm sending 4000 transactions to a cluster involving an RPC and a validator using JMeter. A significant portion of these transactions are failing, consistently producing the following error:

```
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:210)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.streamRead(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:137)
at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.fillBuffer(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:153)
at org.apache.http.impl.io.SessionInputBufferImpl.readLine(SessionInputBufferImpl.java:280)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:138)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpResponseParser.parseHead(DefaultHttpResponseParser.java:56)
at org.apache.http.impl.io.AbstractMessageParser.parse(AbstractMessageParser.java:259)
at org.apache.http.impl.DefaultBHttpClientConnection.receiveResponseHeader(DefaultBHttpClientConnection.java:163)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.CPoolProxy.receiveResponseHeader(CPoolProxy.java:157)
at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.doReceiveResponse(HttpRequestExecutor.java:273)
at org.apache.http.protocol.HttpRequestExecutor.execute(HttpRequestExecutor.java:125)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:272)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:186)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.executeRequest(HTTPHC4Impl.java:939)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPHC4Impl.sample(HTTPHC4Impl.java:650)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerProxy.sample(HTTPSamplerProxy.java:66)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1301)
at org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase.sample(HTTPSamplerBase.java:1290)
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.doSampling(JMeterThread.java:651)
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:570)
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:501)
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:268)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
```

I'm keen to understand if anyone else has encountered a similar issue in the past. Specifically, I'm interested in learning about any parameters or configurations related to the RPC that might impact the number of connections it can handle. Additionally, I'm curious if there are ways to adjust settings to allow the RPC to handle a higher volume of transactions.

Your insights, suggestions, or any relevant information would be immensely valuable in resolving this issue.

Best regards

Comment: Chain is down currently, so that's probably why. You can track it here: https://status.solana.com/

Comment: Hi, thank you, I am talking about a private cluster, it is not the mainnet, I have set up an rpc on a private server and also a validator on another server

Comment: There's some detail missing here -- the stack trace doesn't tell us too much unfortunately. If you're getting `Connection reset`, it might be that you're trying to do too many concurrent connections to your RPC node. You can try increasing `--rpc-threads` when starting up your RPC node to give it some more processing power.

Comment: Hi,

I have resolved the issue by changing the machine from which I send transactions. The main difference with the machine I was using before is:

Frequency: 2.70 GHz (previously 1.20 GHz)
Operating System: Windows 11 (previously Windows 10)


After this change, the executions were 100% successful.